# Variable white LED strip hookup

Tags: led, wiring, diagram

I plan on assembling 8+ rolls(16.4ft per) of variable white LED strip which has 3 connections. +, CW, WW.
I need to control these 8 rolls with one remote. 
Here’s the schematic I have:
PSU to controller to beginning of all 8 LED strips connected, then adding additional power to each led strip(+). Would this method work?
I've attached some quick schematics as well.[image: Schematic of Variable White Hook-up]

Comment: You might be better off, here, explaining in more detail exactly what you want to achieve (and NOT achieve) in order to carefully bound the problem without asking us to make assumptions about your needs. And then ask for an appropriate topology with functional blocks. You could then do some research on your own about the function blocks and come back with an improved question, if needed.

Comment: What I want to achieve is a setup to where I can control 8 lengths/rolls of LED strip lighting with one remote. Wattage + Volts does not matter as I have that figured out. I just would like to know whether adding power to each additional strip is a method that works.

Comment: The word "control" is "mostly meaningless." Even with the added "variable" to your description. I could assume. But I won't. You need to write out how these things will be positioned, where the supply will be placed, where the controls will be at, what kind of controls they are (in detail), perhaps how you intend on connecting the strips (lengths and type of wire, etc) and ANYTHING ELSE you can imagine. I do not have a working crystal ball. For example, by "variable" do you mean "linearly variable as perceived by human perception?" Be detailed.

Comment: The schematic makes no sense. I wanted to point out what's wrong with it, but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: The 'schematic' shows the control signal wire connected to the positive supply line, which is connected to the negative supply line. There is no delineation of the wires to the LED strips. The last time I connected a negative and positive line together on a power supply things blew up literally. Please clarify your schematic. Provide a model number and link for the LED strips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about colour adjustable cool / warm white LEDs then the chances are you have something like this:

[image]

*Figure 1. CW/WW LED strip wiring. Source: [DenoLED](http://www.denoled.com/products/led-strip-light/Color-Temperature-Adjustable-3528-LED-Strip-Super-Bright-new.html).*

- Note that there will be a limit to how many rolls you can connect in series as the first has to carry the current for all.
  -Note also how the wiring diagram shows the strips wired in a "star topology" from the power supply.

It is not enough just to loop the positive supply to each strip. Each strip requires a ground return through the controller.

You have given no specification, link or datasheet for the controller. You need to find this and work out how many strips it can handle. i.e., What is the maximum current (amps) or power (watts) it can handle.

If you find that your controller cannot handle all the LEDs then purchase a second identical controller. Both will respond to the infrared remote in the same manner giving the appearance of a single control.

Comment: The addressable chip buffers the signals with respect to that IC's ground. So be careful with noise currents that shift the ground on those signals and choose wire and voltage drop accordingly.  Some chips are rated only for 6m cascades not 40m that's why a Star Topology is needed for each strip.

Comment: I think they're not addressable - just pairs of cool and warm white LEDs on a common positive with two switched negatives.